# Checking if this vector field is conservative.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

> The vector field is $\vec F(x,y)=P(x,y)\hat i+Q(x,y)\hat j$. While:
> $P(x,y)=\frac{4yx^7}{\sqrt{x^8+y^6}}$ whenever $(x,y)\ne0$ and otherwise equal $0$. 
> $Q(x,y)=\frac{3y^6}{\sqrt{x^8+y^6}}+\sqrt{x^8+y^6}$ whenever $(x,y)\ne0$ and
> otherwise equal $0$.

First of all, I know that if $Q_x\ne P_y$ the field isn't conservative, I went up and checked that and found that: 
$P_y=Q_x=4x^7(\sqrt{x^8+y^6}-\frac{3y^6}{\sqrt{x^8+y^6}})$. 
And now I'm a little confused on what to do, I know that if $P,Q$ have a continuous partial derivatives in a simply connected space. and $P_y=Q_x$
in every point in that space. then $\vec F=Pi+Qj$ is a conserative field in that space. 

Now in order to prove continuity of $P_y,Q_x$ or even $P,Q$ themselves, I need to show that $\lim_{(x,y)}\to0$. But I'm struggling to calculate the limit. 
Would appreciate any help and feedback, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_x|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=\operatorname{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(h,0)-P(0,0)}{h}=0$. Similarly you can find $Q_y|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=0$. Now it is easy to easy the term $4x^7(\sqrt{x^8+y^6})\rightarrow 0 $ as $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$. The other term is $\frac{12x^7y^6}{\sqrt{x^8+y^6}}$. Now $y^6\leq (x^8+y^6)$. Hence $|\frac{12x^7y^6}{\sqrt{x^8+y^6}}|\leq \frac{12|x|^7(x^8+y^6)}{\sqrt{x^8+y^6}}=12|x|^7\sqrt{x^8+y^6}\rightarrow0$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$. This shows the continuity of $Q_y,P_x$ at $0$. The continuity at all other points are trivial. As $\mathbb{R}^2$ is obviously simply connected, you are done.

EDIT: I have simplified the calculation a little.

Comment: @Satwana Hans thanks alot! could you please elaborate on the step $|y|=(y^6)^{\frac{1}{6}}\le ...$ and the next step? I didn't quite get how could you conclude that, and if possible, I would love to hear what were your thoughts that led you to write it like that! Thanks again!

Comment: The idea is always this, if the total power in the numerator is greater than the total power in the denominator, then the limit exists and is 0. Now to show this, you need to somehow be able to cancel the denominator, so you have to manipulate the numerator to cancel the denominator. Now $y^6\leq x^8+y^8$ (since $x^8$ is positive), then you take the power, hence $(y^6)^{1/6}\leq (x^8+y^6)^{1/6}$.